# VMware Fusion Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server - Soft Lockup CPU Stuck

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04, cpu-usage, vmware-fusion

I have a strange Stuck Problem with VMware Fusion and Ubuntu 12.04 as Guest System. On High Loaded process the System stucks with "Soft Lockup CPU Stuck" and i have to reboot the VM...the Same System via VirtualBox works fine but VirtualBox Performance are bad...especially I/O...This happens if i use 2 CPU Cores...with only 1 CPU Core the VM under VMware Fusion works without any Problem...but i need 2 Cores...any fixes for that?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having this problem with VMWare Fusion 6, Ubuntu 12.04 on Mac OS X Mavericks.